# After upgrading GitLab, two different psql/postgres versions

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, upgrade

We recently did a GitLab upgrade from 11.x up to 12.9.2. It all went well; however, when I do gitlab-ctl pg-upgrade it shows the DB being 10.12. But when I do gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info it shows 10.7.

If I drop into gitlab-rails dbconsole it shows:

psql (10.12, server 10.7)

I didn't originally set this server or instance up. Any idea why it would be showing two different versions (does 10.12 mean the client is 10.12, the server is still 10.7?) Ideally the server would be 10.12.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question after further digging.

I ran a stat on /opt/gitlab/embedded/postgresql/10/bin/postgres and it showed that it was indeed changed when we did the upgrade.

Then I ran an lsof and saw that the postgres process had this binary open with a (deleted) marker, meaning it had the previous file still open in memory.

I ran a gitlab-ctl stop and a gitlab-ctl start and now it's showing properly when I do gitlab-rails dbconsole.

Should've done all that first!